# Solve almostIncreasingSequence on CodeSignal in Dart

Tags: arrays, for-loop, dart

The description:

> Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.
>
> Note: sequence a0, a1, ..., an is considered to be a strictly increasing if a0 < a1 < ... < an. Sequence containing only one element is also considered to be strictly increasing.
>
> ## Example
>
> For sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1], the output should be
>       `almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = false.`
>
> There is no one element in this array that can be removed in order to get a strictly increasing sequence.
>
> For sequence = [1, 3, 2], the output should be
>       `almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = true.`
>
> You can remove 3 from the array to get the strictly increasing sequence [1, 2]. Alternately, you can remove 2 to get the strictly increasing sequence [1, 3].
>
> ## Input/Output
>
> **[execution time limit]** 4 seconds (dart)
>
> **[input]** array.integer sequence
>
> Guaranteed constraints:
>
> `2 ≤ sequence.length ≤ 105,`
>
> `-105 ≤ sequence[i] ≤ 105.`
>
> **[output]** boolean
>           Return true if it is possible to remove one element from the array in order to get a strictly increasing sequence, otherwise return false.

After a while trying and debugging, i've come to this beautiful solution:

```dart
bool almostIncreasingSequence(List<int> sequence) {
    int decreseCounter = 0;
    int duplicateCounter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sequence.length - 1; i++){

        if(sequence[i] >= sequence[i + 1]) decreseCounter++; //Check for decreasing pairs 
        if(decreseCounter > 1) return false;

    }
    for(int i = 0; i < sequence.length - 2; i++){

        if(sequence[i] == sequence[i + 2]) duplicateCounter++; //Check for duplicate pairs
        if(duplicateCounter > 1) return false;


        if(sequence[i] >= sequence[i + 1] // Check for cliffs (elements that follow by two smaller or equal elements)
        && sequence[i] >= sequence[i + 2]
        && (i > 0 && i < sequence.length - 3)) return false;

    }

    return true;

}
```

This code performed very well with all the "not hidden" tests and any list that i gave it! But when i submitted it, the code failed on just ONE hidden test! Any ideas why did it failed?

Answer (score 0):

It says `[1,2,3,1,2]` is true which is not the case. I guess you don't want a solution since the task is about learning, so I will not give one unless you tell me otherwise.